# how to map an DataFrame to an EdgeRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame like:

```
val data = sc.parallelize(Array((1,10,10,7,7),(2,7,7,7,8),(3, 5,5,6,8))).toDF("id","col1","col2","col3","col4")
```

What I want to do is to create an EdgeRDD where two ids share a link if they share the same value in at least one of the columns

```
id col1 col2 col3 col4
 1   10   10    7    7
 2    7    7    7    8
 3    5    5    6    8
```

then node 1 and 2 have an undirected link 1--2, because they share a common value in col3.

For the same reason, node 2 and 3 share an undirected link because they share a common value in col4

I know how to resolve this in a ugly way (but I have way too many columns to adopt this strategy in my real case)

```
val data2 = data.withColumnRenamed("id", "idd").withColumnRenamed("col1", "col1d").withColumnRenamed("col2", "col2d").withColumnRenamed("col3", "col3d").withColumnRenamed("col4", "col4d")
val res = data.join(data2, data("id") < data2("idd")
                    && (data("col1") === data2("col1d")
                    || data("col2") === data2("col2d")
                    || data("col3") === data2("col3d")
                    || data("col4") === data2("col4d")))
                                              //> res  : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, col1: int, col2: int, col
                                              //| 3: int, col4: int, idd: int, col1d: int, col2d: int, col3d: int, col4d: int
                                              //| ]
res.show                                      //> +---+----+----+----+----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
                                              //| | id|col1|col2|col3|col4|idd|col1d|col2d|col3d|col4d|
                                              //| +---+----+----+----+----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
                                              //| |  1|  10|  10|   7|   7|  2|    7|    7|    7|    8|
                                              //| |  2|   7|   7|   7|   8|  3|    5|    5|    6|    8|
                                              //| +---+----+----+----+----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
                                              //| 
val links = EdgeRDD.fromEdges(res.map(row => Edge(row.getAs[Int]("id").toLong, row.getAs[Int]("idd").toLong, "indirect")))
                                              //> links  : org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.EdgeRDDImpl[String,Nothing] = EdgeRDD
                                              //| Impl[27] at RDD at EdgeRDD.scala:42
links.foreach(println)                        //> Edge(1,2,indirect)
                                              //| Edge(2,3,indirect)
```

how to resolve this for much more columns?

Comment: Could you explain which part you find ugly? `join` condition? And is `data2` just a copy of `data`?

Comment: say I have 100 columns, I don't like to specify the === for each column... there should be a way to automate that part? or maybe not... :(

Comment: yep, sorry, forgot to add that part... just edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
val expr = data.columns.diff(Seq("id"))
  .map(c => data(c) === data2(s"${c}d"))
  .reduce(_ || _)

data.join(data2, data("id") < data2("idd") && expr)
```

You can also use aliases

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val expr = data.columns.diff(Seq("id"))
  .map(c => col(s"d1.$c") === col(s"d2.$c"))
  .reduce(_ || _)

data.alias("d1").join(data.alias("d2"), col("d1.id") < col("d2.id") && expr)
```

You can easily follow each of this by as simple `select` (`$` is equivalent to `col` but requires an import of `sqlContext.implicits.StringToColumn`)

```
.select($"id".cast("long"), $"idd".cast("long"))
```

or

```
.select($"d1.id".cast("long"), $"d2.id".cast("long"))
```

and a pattern matching:

```
.rdd.map { case Row(src: Long, dst: Long) => Edge(src, dst, "indirect") }
```

Just note that logical disjunctions like this one cannot be optimized and **are expanded to a Cartesian product** followed by a `filter`. If you want to avoid you can try to approach this problem in different ways.

Lets start with reshaping data from wide to long:

```
val expr = explode(array(data.columns.tail.map(
  c => struct(lit(c).alias("column"), col(c).alias("value"))
): _*))

val long = data.withColumn("tmp", expr)
  .select($"id", $"tmp.column", $"tmp.value")
```

This will give us a `DataFrame` with a following schema:

```
long.printSchema

// root
//  |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
//  |-- column: string (nullable = false)
//  |-- value: integer (nullable = false)
```

With data like this you have multiple choices including optimized `join`:

```
val pairs = long.as("long1")
  .join(long.as("long2"),
    $"long1.column" === $"long2.column" &&  // Optimized
    $"long1.value" === $"long2.value" &&  // Optimized
    $"long1.id" < $"long2.id" // Not optimized - filtered after sort-merge join
  )
  // Select only ids
  .select($"long1.id".alias("src"), $"long2.id".alias("dst"))
  // And keep distict
  .distinct

pairs.show
// +---+---+
// |src|dst|
// +---+---+
// |  1|  2|
// |  2|  3|
// +---+---+
```

This can further improved by using different hashing techniques to avoid a large number of record generated by explode.

You can also think about this problem as bipartite graph where observations belong to on category of nodes and property-value pairs to another.

```
sealed trait CustomNode
case class Record(id: Long) extends CustomNode
case class Property(name: String, value: Int) extends CustomNode
```

With this as a starting point you can use `long` to generate edges of the following type:

```
Record -> Property
```

and solve this problem using GraphX directly by searching for paths like

```
Record -> Property <- Record
```

Hint: Collect neighbors for each property and propagate back.

Same as before you should consider using hashing or buckets to reduce limit a number of the generated `Property` nodes.

Comment: this solution works in theory, but actually I am not able to run it because it takes too many disk space even for relatively small network of 297 nodes and 300 links... is there any other approach I can try that could be optimized?

Comment: It shouldn't fail with 300 nodes but like I stated before logical alternatives cannot not optimized. So this approach is roughly _O(N^2 * M)_ with N nodes and M features. Is there any other approach? Probably more than one. You can for example consider hashing to look for possible candidates or represent your data as a bipartite graph from the beginning.  It is rather unlikely any of these will fit SO format though.

Comment: representing data as a bipartite graph is not something that comes easy to my mind because nodes belongs to the same set... about "hashing to look for possible candidates", that is not something I understand (I am not a computer scientist)... but thanks for the suggestions, I'll try to google it and see...

Comment: Regarding bipartite graph think about it this way each value of the columns is represented as a node of type A. Each observation with id as a node of type B. In the initial graph edges represent following property B - [has-property] -> A. You can use buckets to reduce amount of the nodes of type A. Next you pass messages to find each pair of B connected by at least one A.

Comment: When it comes to hashing you can start with a simple idea - explode the records to the shape (`id`, `column`, `value`). Lets call this `df`. Next perform a query equivalent: `SELECT DISTINCT df1.id, df2.id FROM df df1 JOIN df df2 WHERE df1.id < df2.id AND df1.column = df.column AND df1.value = df2.value`

Comment: This will give you a baseline solution. Comparing all exploded records is probably something you want to avoid so instead of (`id` `column` `value`) you may choose some (`id` `hash`) where number of hashes << number-of-columns * number-of-values. You join based on hash and then check if this is a true positive.